# Sending the proper http status code upon server side error in Nextjs 13+

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, vercel, next.js13

I'm currently learning how to handle errors in Next.js 13+. I've been following the documentation, and I've come across the notFound() function, which is used to gracefully handle errors. It seems to work similarly for 500 errors, and so on.

However, I've noticed that when a 404 error occurs, the UI displays it as a 404, but the status code of the request in the browser is 200. The same issue happens with 500 errors, where you see the "An error occurred" UI, but the page loads with a 200 status code.

I would like to send the proper HTTP status code to browsers, crawlers, monitoring tools, ect.

How can I achieve that?